# How to identify duplicates in Google Sheets from a Google Docs sign-up form?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-docs

The problem we have, arises from the fact that the online sign-up form we use, can be accessed multiple times by the same user.  We do not want to use the option to restrict that, as e.g. parents/guardians can sign up both themselves and their children, so that is a valid use case for us.

However, some of our clients (due perhaps to poor web connectivity or other issues) end up submitting he same person more than once. So now out lists are inflated and we are double counting these people.

In the past I have in SQL joined a table against itself, as a stratagem to poke out such duplicates. But from Googling this a bit, the SQL type queries available in  Google Sheets do not seem to lend themselves very easily to joins.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If all duplicate entries are identical, then try:
`=UNIQUE([data range])`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use the query function you could count use **select and group by** to group together all duplicates. You could count them too.

### Example:

```js
=QUERY(A:B,"select A, B, count(A) where A!='' group by A, B",1)
```

This will output a list of unique rows and their count.

### References:

[Group by](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Group_By)